# Can we tell if a given rational point is a point on the Sierpiński triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, computability, computational-geometry, fractals

Stated precisely, is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) for the [Sierpiński triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_triangle) restricted to rational points in the plane a [computable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function)? My intuition is telling me no, but maybe the fractal folks know something clever.

In case you're reading the comments, the original question didn't restrict to rational points. This makes the answer to the question flatly *no*, since real numbers are evil.

Comment: I know the definition of computability for a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow{0,1}$, but what is the definition of computability for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow {0,1}$?

Comment: I think you may want to be clearer on the exact notion of computability you are interested in. Considering that equality between real numbers is not computable, even the characteristic function of $\{x: x>0\}$ is not computable. See https://www.fernuni-hagen.de/imperia/md/content/fakultaetfuermathematikundinformatik/forschung/berichte/bericht_298.pdf for a similar problem.

Comment: Given a point, the first finitely many digits of its coordinates might tell you that the point is not in the fractal, but can never tell you that the point is in the fractal. So the indicator function is not computable.

Comment: @Manlio Yeah, the answer to this question is an immediate *no* then just because of the real numbers.

Comment: @AngelaPretorius Yeah, I didn't consider how it's impossible to compute things with real numbers. Does this question become more interesting if you only consider rational points on the Sierpiński triangle?

Comment: It may be worth clarifying what you mean by a "rational point".  The Sierpinski gasket $SG$ is often thought of as the attractor of an iterated function system.  A "rational point" of $SG$ is a point which can be written as the image of one of the fixed points of that system under a finite number of mappings from the system.  However, from your question, it seems that you are interested in $SG \cap \mathbb{Q}^2$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes, I mean $\mathbb{Q}$-rational points that lie on the gasket embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Maybe specify how many of the outermost vertices of the triangle are $\mathbb{Q}$-rational points to begin with, but I don't think this changes the nature of the question.

Comment: @AngelaPretorius rational coordinates have eventually periodic expansions, could that help?

Comment: The same problem has been studied for the Cantor set; see this paper and its bibliography: https://doi.org/10.1007/s10958-015-2630-z